AWS Lambda function url double firing in Chrome only
I am building an inventory system in which a qr code is scanned, which calls the Trello API and adds a card to reorder the appropriate item. To do this, the qr code directs to a functional url that triggers an aws lambda function to send the request. I have built it in python and have it working well, with one catch - if the url is visited in Chrome it posts twice. Anyone have an idea what could cause this and how to avoid it? code is in python, below:
import json
import urllib3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    r = http.request('POST', 'https://api.trello.com/1/cards?key=<mykey>&token=<mytoken>&name=new card&idList=<listid>')
    

I have reducing the code to a bare minimum, expecting at some points results consistent with Firefox and Safari without success.

Are you using IPv6? Could it be a 'Happy Eyeballs' problem where an ipv4 and ipv6 requests are both made?

Add a print(event) statement to the start of the Lambda function and look at the log in CloudWatch Events to see what is being passed to the function. It might help you debug what is happening.

make sure that mykey, mytoken and listid variables are passed as "constants" so that the second invocation will fail silently. This may help. https://cloudonaut.io/your-lambda-function-might-execute-twice-deal-with-it/

I think if it only occurs on Chrome and not other browser then the browser could be sending favicon.ico requests. Since it is the default behavior of Chrome, you can only workaround this by adding a check for favicon.ico requests on the server side and reject them if found

This is a solution i had also considered. It's possible it has an effect, but none of the solutions provided in that post are working at present.
